# Extract from Unix time AM vs. PM

Tags: matlab, unix

I have a unix timestamp (1.500641224636246e+09) and I am not sure how to extract whether it is AM or PM time from it via MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [timeofday](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.timeofday.html) and [datetime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html):

```
>> timestamp = timeofday(datetime(1.500641224636246e+09,'ConvertFrom','posixtime'));
>> isPM = timestamp > hours(12) + minutes(0) + seconds(0)
isPM =

  logical

   1
```